# Can't clone git from GitLab in Windows

Tags: windows, git, ssh, gitlab

I have a problem only with one repository from my GitLab. I think it depends on the count of objects on the repository. Smaller projects were cloned successfully. Https doesn't work neither Linux nor Windows. In Windows I get the error:

```sh
........................................
........................................
remote: Counting objects: 100% (988/988)        
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: protocol error: bad pack header
```

I also tried to clone the repository in my LAN network (ping < 1 ms). Same issue.
In Linux, I can clone the repository via ssh. But in Windows with the same private key, I get error about Invalid format in the private key. Key is the same as loaded in Linux OS. But if I tried to connect via ssh to GitLab (git@git.domain) the connection will be (Just ssh without `git clone`). I even see the welcome message.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly the right forum I chose (StackOverflow or StackExchange), but there are more similar questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is a workaround in https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1315.